# SQL Server Database Diagrams error

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting an error when I try to expand Database Diagrams section for one of my databases.

[image]

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

I cannot find any information regarding this online :(

I've tried to restart SQL Server.
I've also tried to take a backup of database, remove existing database and then restoring it hoping that it might give it a refresh but that didn't make a difference.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.
I had to remove a row from sysdiagrams table for that database.

There was a row with a NULL in diagram_id column so this was causing an issue.
I removed that and it's all fine now.